# Как устроены составные индексы? На примере PostgreSQL.

Tags: postgresql, sql

1) есть 2 поля - varchar 'text' и int 'value'. По ним создан индекс:

> CREATE INDEX idx_index_value_and_text
> ON index_test ( value, text )

Пишу:

> select * from index_test r where
> r.text='some value'

Анализатор говорит:

> Index Scan using
> idx_index_value_and_text on index_test

Вопрос: как он может искать по индексу, если первая колонка не указана? В терминах  B-Tree - что представляет собой составной индекс: единое дерево, значения нод которого есть concatenation строк значений входящих в него полей?

2) Данный поиск в зависимости от распределения значений колонок имеет разные типы: Bitmap Heap Scan и Bitmap Index Scan, либо Index Scan если распределение достаточное ровное. Что означают Bitmap-типы, чем отличается Bitmap Index Scan от Index Scan? Кроме того, есть ли в Postgres Index Range Scan?

Comment: > Вопрос: как он может искать по индексу, если первая колонка не указана? 

Так он и не ищет -  скан - это просмотр страниц подряд, а не поиск.

Comment: Это Seq Scan, а тут Index Scan.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Составной индекс, в отличие от "одинарного" индекса в качестве индексируемого значения использует не одно значение, а несколько значений то есть если есть 2 поля A и B то составной индекс по ним будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
| A | B | 
---------
| 1 | 1 | 
| 1 | 2 | 
| 1 | 4 | 
| 2 | 2 | 
| 2 | 3 | 
| 2 | 5 |
```

Грубо говоря это сортировка по двум полям, а не одному полю. То есть это не индексирование конкатенированных значений A+B.

На уровне BTree это выглядит как будто листочки BTree отвечающие за поле A, ссылаются на вложенное дерево BTree отвечающее за поле B.

Сканирование индекса в вашем случае фактически означает, что поскольку первое поле у вас не задано, то сервер сканирует все листочки дерева A, чтобы найти подходящее значение поля B.

Составной индекс полезен когда информация может быть кластеризована: скажем по этому принципу устроены словари/энциклопедии. Вам нужна статья на букву "Д" - вы находите по оглавлению раздел на букву "Д" и далее ищете нужную статью. А вот если нужна статья заканчивающаяся на "К" - то кластеризация уже не поможет - придется рыться во всей книге (сканировать индекс).

Comment: Спасибо, непонятен остался все-таки главный вопрос: почему он ищет по индексу, если условие поиска включает в себя только ВТОРУЮ колонку, вот что странно.

Comment: Объём индекса и объём данных. Читать меньше, соответственно, быстрее.

Comment: Если я правильно понял суть, здесь имеет место full-index-scan, когда все нужные запросу данные содержаться в индексе. Даже при том что искать по нему как по BTree нельзя, все равно проще взять значения из индекса, а не из таблицы.